# Как программно очистить поле типа integer в sql запросе?

Tags: sql, delphi

Имеется таблица access. Подключена через делфи. Пытаюсь очистить поле через запрос SQL, однако выпадает ошибка о несоответствии типов данных.

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('UPDATE по_учет SET ПК=:q WHERE код=:w ');
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('q').Value := '';
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('w').Value := DBGridEh1.DataSource.DataSet.Fields.Fields[0].text;
```

Comment: установить в 0 или NULL если второй не запрещен.

Answer (score 0):

Установить в 0 или NULL если второй не запрещен:

```
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('q').Value := 0;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('q').Value := null;
```